# Show that the points P = (3.5, 9.5) and Q = (2.5, 8.5) lie on the elliptic curve ($y^2 = x^3 – 36x$) over the real numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elliptic-curves

I am studying elliptic curve cryptography and know basics of elliptic curve(just as much I require in solving these sort of problems)
I am doing this problem and totally confused as when I try to do this for P=(3.5,9.5), I get 90.25 on L.H.S and -83.125 on R.H.S, as much as I can understand from the question I can conclude that modulus operator is not required here as we are doing operations over real number and not some $Z_P$ where p is prime.

Comment: $x^3-36x=x(x^2-36)$ is negative, when $x<-6$ or $0<x<6$. So if $x\in(0,6)$ then $y\notin\Bbb{R}$. Also, if $x=n+1/2$ for some integer $n$, then $x^3-36x$ has denominator equal to $8$ (together with an odd numerator), so it cannot be the square of a rational number.

Comment: And the denominators are wrong too. When $x=7/2$ or $5/2$, the denominator on the right is $8$, while that is not possible for the square of a rational number (from the left). This thing is totally bollixed up.

Answer (score 0):

Something is amiss.  Neither of those points lie on the elliptic curve $y^2 = x^2 - 36x$.  This can be seen by directly plugging in the points, but notice that, more generally, $x^2 - 36x < 0$ if $x \in (0,36).$  And both $3.5$ and $2.5$ are in $(0,36)$.  But the LHS is nonnegative for all real $y$.

**EDIT:**  Regarding your changing it to $x^3 - 36x$, the exact same argument applies except now the interval is $(0,6)$ instead of $(0,36)$.  Note that $x^3 - 36x < 0$ if (but not **only if**, but that's not really relevant here) $x \in (0,6)$.  And both $2.5$ and $3.5$ are in $(0,6)$.  Same issue occurs.

Comment: sorry I made it wrong I have corrected it, please recheck.

Comment: @Ankit, same problem occurs, see my update.

Comment: may be the question is misprinted!!!

Comment: @Ankit, sounds like it.